# Como marcar la seleccion de un div al dar click sobre el en Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, eventos, div, contenedores

Tengo 3 contenedores (div) quiero que al dar click sobre uno de estos se resalte el que estoy seleccionando.
No se cual clase de css me pueda ayudar o si en su efecto tendria que usar una funcion.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import '../assets/styles/OptionContainer.css';

const OptionContainer = (props) => {

  return (
    <section className='itemsSelected'>
      <div className='rows'>
        Filas
        <br />
        <button className='btnSelect'></button>
      </div>
      <article className='container_col_val'>
        <div className='columns'>
          Columnas
        <br />
        <button className='btnSelect'></button>
        </div>
        <div className='values'>
          Valores
        <br />
          <button className='btnSelect'></button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  )
}

export default OptionContainer;
```

Asi se ven los contenedores, necesito que cuando selecciones uno, por ej filas este se resalte y se mantenga activo, pero si doy click en otro entonces el otro sea el que se active y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un hook como `React.useState` para definir un estado que te permita saber cual es el elemento activo en todo momento. El estado que definas puede ser un `index` o cualquier clase de identificador que te permita diferenciar un elemento de otro, de esa forma sabras cuando aplicarle el estado activo o no.

Puedes usar el siguiente ejemplo como referencia (presiona ejecutar y verás como funciona):

```css
/* estilos básicos para los containers a modo de ejemplo: */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: .4rem;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.container:hover {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

/* los containers con la clase "active" tendrán un background naranjado: */
.container.active {
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.12.4/babel.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  function Container({ active, onClick }) {
     // cada container recibe una propiedad booleana "active"
     // si la propiedad es "true", se agrega la clase "active" al elemento.
     // adicionalmente se añade un listener al evento click:
     return (
      <div className={`container ${active ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={onClick}></div>
    );
  }

  function App() {
    // aqui uso un indice como estado para saber cual es el elemento
    // activo en un momento dado:
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(null);
    // "null" por defecto, para indicar que no hay elemento activo al principio

    // con este handler actualizo el indice activo cada vez que
    // presiona click sobre alguno de los elementos:
    const onClickHandler = (index) => {
      setActiveIndex(index);
    };

    // la vista simplemente consiste en asignar un indice a cada elemento,
    // el primer elemento es el indice 0, el segundo es 1 y así sucesivamente...
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Container active={activeIndex === 0} onClick={() => onClickHandler(0)} />
        <Container active={activeIndex === 1} onClick={() => onClickHandler(1)} />
        <Container active={activeIndex === 2} onClick={() => onClickHandler(2)} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);
</script>
```